# Inserting echo via mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am aiming to insert the respective learning style into the database if the echo statement has been triggered by the if statement. The DB columns are as follows: studentNumber, dimension1, dimension2, dimension3, dimension4. Any feedback would be appreciated. Trialing 'mildly active' hence the statement only being present at that stage of the code.

```
<?php
    $active =0;
    $reflective=0;
    $sensing=0;
    $intuitive=0;
    $visual=0;
    $verbal=0;
    $sequential=0;
    $global=0;
    $mildlyActive = "Mildly Active";
    $moderatelyActive = "Moderately Active";
    $stronglyActive = "Strongly Active";
    $mildlyReflective = "Mildly Reflective";
    $moderatelyReflective = "Moderately Reflective";
    $stronglyReflective = "Strongly Reflective";
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
            if($key != "submit"){
                $dbQuery1 = $db->prepare("select * FROM answer WHERE answerID = '".$value."'");
                $dbQuery1-> execute();
                while ($dbRow = $dbQuery1->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    $answerTypeID=$dbRow["answerTypeID"];
                    $dbQuery2 = $db->prepare("select * FROM answerType WHERE answerTypeID = '".$answerTypeID."'");
                    $dbQuery2-> execute();
                    while ($dbRow2=$dbQuery2->fetch()){
                        $answerType=$dbRow2["answerType"];
                        //echo $answerType;
                        if ($answerType=='active'){
                            $active++;
                        }
                        if ($answerType=='reflective'){
                            $reflective++;
                        }
                        if ($answerType=='sensing'){
                            $sensing++;
                        }
                        if ($answerType=='intuitive'){
                            $intuitive++;
                        }
                        if ($answerType=='visual'){
                            $visual++;
                        }
                        if ($answerType=='verbal'){
                            $verbal++;
                        }
                        if ($answerType=='sequential'){
                            $sequential++;
                        }
                        if ($answerType=='global'){
                            $global++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                $dbQuery=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO `userResponse` VALUES (:studentID, :questionID, :answerID)");
                $dbParams=array('studentID'=>$_SESSION["currentUser"], 'questionID'=>$key, 'answerID'=>$value);
                $dbQuery->execute($dbParams); 
            }
        }
    }
    if ($active>$reflective){
        $total =  $active - $reflective;
        if ($total == 1){
            echo "Mildly active";
            $dbQuery=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO indexLearningStyle (dimension1) VALUE (:mildlyActive)");     
        }
        if ($total == 2){
            echo "Mildly active";
            $dbQuery=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO indexLearningStyle (dimension1) VALUE (:mildlyActive)"); 
        }
        if($total == 3){
            echo "Moderately active";
        }
        if($total == 4){
            echo "Moderately active";
        }
        if ($total == 5){
            echo "Strongly active";
        } 
    }
    else {
        $total =  $reflective - $active;
        if ($total == 1){
            echo "Mildly reflective";
        }
        if ($total == 2){
            echo "Mildly reflective";
        }
        if ($total == 3){
            echo "Moderately reflective";
        }
        if ($total == 4){
            echo "Moderately reflective";
        }
        if ($total == 5){
            echo "Strongly reflective";
        }
    }
    if ($sensing>$intuitive){
        $total =  $sensing - $intuitive;
        if ($total == 1){
            echo "Mildly sensing";
        }
        if ($total == 2){
            echo "Mildly sensing";
        }
        if($total == 3){
            echo "Moderately sensing";
        }
        if($total == 4){
            echo "Moderately sensing";
        }
        if ($total == 5){
            echo "Strongly sensing";
        } 
    }
    else {
        $total =  $intuitive - $sensing;
        if ($total == 1){
            echo "Mildly intuitive";
        }
        if ($total == 2){
            echo "Mildly intuitive";
        }
        if ($total == 3){
            echo "Moderately intuitive";
        }
        if ($total == 4){
            echo "Moderately intuitive";
        }
        if ($total == 5){
            echo "Strongly intuitive";
        }
    }
    if ($visual>$verbal){
        $total =  $visual - $verbal;
        if ($total == 1){
            echo "Mildly visual";
        }
        if ($total == 2){

            echo "Mildly visual";
        }
        if($total == 3){
            echo "Moderately visual";
        }
        if($total == 4){
            echo "Moderately visual";
        }
        if ($total == 5){
            echo "Strongly visual";
        } 
    }
    else {
        $total =  $verbal - $visual;
        if ($total == 1){
            echo "Mildly verbal";
        }
        if ($total == 2){
            echo "Mildly verbal";
        }
        if ($total == 3){
            echo "Moderately verbal";
        }
        if ($total == 4){
            echo "Moderately verbal";
        }
        if ($total == 5){
            echo "Strongly verbal";
        }
    }
    if ($sequential>$global){
        $total =  $sequential - $global;
        if ($total == 1){
            echo "Mildly sequential";
        }
        if ($total == 2){
            echo "Mildly sequential";
        }
        if($total == 3){
            echo "Moderately sequential";
        }
        if($total == 4){
            echo "Moderately sequential";
        }
        if ($total == 5){
            echo "Strongly sequential";
        } 
    }
    else {
        $total =  $global - $sequential;
        if ($total == 1){
            echo "Mildly global";
        }
        if ($total == 2){
            echo "Mildly global";
        }
        if ($total == 3){
            echo "Moderately global";
        }
        if ($total == 4){
            echo "Moderately global";
        }
        if ($total == 5){
            echo "Strongly global";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Comment: This code is rife with needless repetition. You really need to learn more about `array`, `for` loops, and effective use of associative arrays to map one value to another in a single line of code. For example, "1" always refers to "mildly" and the adjective is just bolted on, so there's no need for X instances of otherwise identical code.